# DAE model as xml

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I am doing a small piece of work with related to ThreeJS.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load(path, function (collada) {
var dae = collada.scene;
dae.position.set(0, 0, 0);  
scene.add(dae); 
}, function () { }, function (result) { console.log(result); });
```

This code is working file if i load actual dae file.

But now am trying to load the XML from DAE. Kindly suggest me how should i approach with this.

I tried the code below to parse the xml and load the 3d model. Its not working.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(path, "text/xml");
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.parse(xml, function (collada) {
    collada.scene.traverse(function (node) {
        if (node.material) node.material.map = dummyTexture;
    });
    signals.objectAdded.dispatch(collada.scene);
    signals.objectSelected.dispatch(collada.scene);
});
```

Please suggest how to load the 3d xml to collada loader.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse Collada XML directly, you can use this pattern:

```
var loader = new THREE.FileLoader();

loader.load( url, function ( text ) {

    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

    var path = THREE.LoaderUtils.extractUrlBase( url );

    var collada = loader.parse( text, path );

    var dae = collada.scene;

    scene.add( dae );

} );
```

three.js r.88

Comment: Can i pass XML instead of URL?

Comment: I am trying to XML to this function and render the model, because if i pass file path as url the loader will not load.                                                                                    Thats the reason i am trying to pass the dae as xml. Please suggest.